# Remote (free) SVN Host

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, host

I'm sure this has been asked a thousand times but in my initial search I couldn't come across anything that seemed to answer my question, hence why I'm typing this :)

We have a few developers starting a new side project. Each of us are in different locations. We (I) want to use SVN to manage the code. Using something like Dropbox would work, but it would just be a huge pain since SVN can take care of the merging and all that as well.

Are there any free sites that will allow me to set something like this up, or any ways to do it myself? We are NOT open source, as I know some sites will let you do this only if your open source.

Ideal situation would be to each have a local Tortoise SVN client on our machines, with a local repo of files that are synced to a remote location containing the official repo of files.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to pay to have a private (non-open source) project hosted for you.

Comment: @slandau, your question implies that you could host the repo yourself is that true?

Comment: @DougChamberlain - kind of. I'd prefer a remote host, but if I have to host one myself, I have an extra PC lying around that could probably do the trick.

Comment: Of course this doesn't answer the question, but any particular reason you can't use mercurial or git?  Bitbucket and github are both excellent, and bitbucket (mercurial) offers unlimited free private repos.

Comment: @Dave - honestly, it's more of just the fact that I am used to SVN and the other guys haven't used version control before so it would be easy for me to teach them that :)

Comment: @slandau Yeah totally get where you're coming from.  However.... the syntax of mercurial is pretty similar to svn, you might check out hginit.com when you have a chance.

Comment: simply go to xp-dev or silksvn to see the largest subversion businesses.  they both have free plans you can go ahead and use.  it's that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the [Subversion Hosting Webpage](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/).

Free hosting, unlimited developers, unlimited modules, unlimited size brings up the following:

- [Google](http://code.google.com/hosting/)
- [BerliOS Deviloper](http://developer.berlios.de/)
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/)
- [Gna](http://gna.org/)
- [Assembla](http://offers.assembla.com/free-subversion-hosting/?affiliate=ianterrell)

Of course, another possibility is to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/). The advantage of Git is that you can work without necessarily having your source repository always up, running, and available. Git will allow you to share your changes via email.

I find Git a bit harder to use than Subversion, and I am not thrilled with the way it keeps everything as patches. However, in situations like yours where you have a half dozen or so people sharing source and no real centralized server, it can be much more convenient than Subversion.

---

## EDIT

I forgot you mentioned that this is not an open source project. However, you can still go to the [Subversion Hosting Webpage](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/). One of the options is to check *non-oss*. Assembla offers free non-oss hosting.

Git is still a good option if you don't want a public server. You can submit patches to each other via email, and you wouldn't even need a server. You can put the Git repository on Dropbox, but let your team members know not to push changes to it: Only fetch the latest changes and submit your changes to the gatekeeper via email.

<strike>**Another possibility**: You might be able to share your Subversion repository via Dropbox. Each user can run svnserve on their own system. I'll have to check with the Subversion developers about the safety of this, though. Accessing the repository via `file://` might be safer.</strike>

*Nope: I just checked with the Subversion developers. This is a definite no-no.*

Comment: He should still go to the [Subversion Hosting Webpage](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/) and see what there is there. You can select non-OSS as one of the options. Assembla does allow non-open source projects. I didn't check that as an option.

Comment: @DavidW. - sharing an SVN repo through Dropbox is a unique idea, haven't thought of that. Still would get all the features but be able to use an easy tool like Dropbox. Not really sure the simplest way to set that up would be though.

Comment: My main concern would be what happens if two people commit at the same time. I'm contacting a couple of the SVN developers I know about it. W/ multiple people, Git would work a bit cleaner since you can all pull code, but not push it back. You can share patches via email, and the gatekeeper would push the code back.

Comment: @DavidW. - gotcha. Also, using the website you shared, I found http://www.projectlocker.com/. It looks good but kind of "scammy". I don't know if that's just me being dumb. I'll check it out though. Thanks!

Comment: @slandau: Projectlocker is pretty well known. However, you might want to read [this blog entry](http://www.bemasher.net/archives/tag/projectlocker) about its limitations

Comment: Thanks for that blog post. We have a team of 3, with one designer, so even if our 2 developers have access to it and the designer has to kind of work around a little bit it's probably not a huge deal.

Comment: I know you wanted a free solution, but you might consider some of the "nearly free" offerings like http://devZing.com

Answer (score 2):

Install Collabnet Subversion Edge.  It is a all in one, apache/svn/web svn interface that is very hassle free.

http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

Answer (score 0):

I have found VisualSVN to be very easy to set up if you have a spare box lying around to host it.

If you want it to be remote, I would consider Assembla. I think that's who I'm using on that "side project I really should be working on more". They're free AND private. (A lot of free hosting sites require it to be open.)

Comment: I'll have to check Assembla out. I do have a spare box (kind of old but it would do). I wanted to find an online remote host since I thought that would be less hassle, but if I can't find anything simple maybe I'll give this a shot.

Comment: VisualSVN Server is good, but the free version you cannot remote create repo/manage user/group etc.